# Does Sling allow Component Filters configured to target only certain resource types?

Tags: osgi, servlet-filters, aem, sling

I've found [Sling's ability to associate Servlets](http://sling.apache.org/site/servlets.html) with certain resource types, selectors and extentions, methods really useful in component development.

Now I'm starting to look into the ComponentFilterChain & would like to create filters that only register against certain resource types, in the same way as Servlets above.

From the [Example filters on the Sling project](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/filters/HttpServiceExtFilter.java), I see that there's a `pattern` property that you can apply for particular paths, though it feels like this limits the benefit of having components.

Really what I'm looking for is an equivalent property to `sling.servlet.resourceType` that I can annotate my Filter with so that only certain components enter this filter as part of the component filter chain, rather than having to check the component `resourceType`/`superResourceType` within the Filter.

Is this possible with Sling filters? Or is there an equivalent approach that can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, there's no way to associate servlet Filters with Sling resource types. Composing OSGi services, maybe using sling:resourceType values set as service properties, should allow you to provide similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. Do you mean passing the `sling:resourceType` to the Filter via a Property annotation & choosing to operate on the request, or let it pass through, based on this from within the Filter?

Comment: What I mean is creating OSGi services with service properties (@Property annotations) similar to what Sling Servlets use. You can then retrieve such services via BundleContext.getServiceReferences(java.lang.Class<S> clazz, java.lang.String serviceFilter) where serviceFilter is an LDAP-like filter that allows you to select services based on those properties.

Answer (score 1):

As of Apache Sling 2.6.14, there is an option to associate Sling Filters with resource types.

The property you need to add to your OSGi service to achieve this is `sling.filter.resourceTypes`.

There's a [set of annotations](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-servlets-annotations/) available that make the job easier.

From the [Sling Documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html#slingservletfilter-annotation)

```
   //...
   import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletFilter;
   import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletFilterScope;
   import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

   @Component
   @SlingServletFilter(scope = {SlingServletFilterScope.REQUEST},
                       suffix_pattern = "/suffix/foo",
                       resourceTypes = {"foo/bar"},
                       pattern = "/content/.*",
                       extensions = {"txt","json"},
                       selectors = {"foo","bar"},
                       methods = {"GET","HEAD"})
   public class FooBarFilter implements Filter {

       // ... implementation
   }
```